# FFMPEG compiled with alsa, but still "Unknown input format: 'alsa'"

Tags: alsa, ffmpeg

Faced problem with ffmpeg+alsa.

Running, for example ***sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 -t 30 out.wav***
gives me:

```
...Unknown input format: 'alsa'...
```

**Checking for alsa:**

I compiled on config with next setup.

Running ***./ffmpeg -formats |grep alsa***  in  ffmpeg dir:

```
...DE alsa            ALSA audio output...
```

Running ***cat config.h | grep ALSA*** in same dir:

```
...
#define CONFIG_ALSA 1
#define CONFIG_ALSA_INDEV 1
#define CONFIG_ALSA_OUTDEV 1
...
```

Now I have no idea at all.
Recompiling with same config gave nothing.

Comment: Where did you install the compiled program *to*? `./ffmpeg` won't necessarily be running the same binary as `sudo ffmpeg`

Comment: @steeldriver damn... That was so stupid, I can't believe I missed it. Thanks!